# Probability of getting heads among loaded coins

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We are given 3 coins with respective probabilities of heads 1/2, 3/5, 1/5. If a coin is tossed at random from the three and it lands on heads what is the probability that the fair coin was tossed?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Using law of total probability,

$$\Pr\{ \text{Getting a head} \} = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \Pr\{\text{picking coin }i\} \Pr\{ \text{Getting a head | picking coin }i \}$$

and using Bayes rule; Probability that fair coin i.e., coin $1$ was tossed given the outcome being heads is,

$$ \Pr\{ \text{picking coin 1 | Getting a head} \} = \frac{\Pr\{ \text{picking coin 1} \}}{  \Pr\{ \text{Getting a head} \}} \cdot \Pr\{ \text{Getting a head | picking coin 1} \}.$$

Observe that, $\Pr\{ \text{Getting a head | picking coin 1} \} = 0.5,~ \Pr\{ \text{Getting a head | picking coin 2} \} = 3/5,~ \Pr\{ \text{Getting a head | picking coin 3} \} = 1/5$ and $\Pr\{ \text{picking coin i} \} = \frac{1}{3}.$